# Groovy/Jenkins: when are variables null, when are they empty strings, and when are they missing?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm trying to grok the rules surrounding variables in Groovy/Jenkinsfiles/declarative syntax.

The generic webhook trigger captures HTTP POST content and makes them available as variables available to your Jenkinsfile. E.g.:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  triggers {
    GenericTrigger (
      genericVariables: [
        [ key: "POST_actor_name", value: "\$.actor.name" ]
      ],

      token: "foo"
    )
  }

  stages {

    stage( "Set up" ) {
      steps {
        script {
          echo "env var ${env.actor_name}"
          echo "global var ${actor_name}"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

If the HTTP POST content contains a JSON object with an `actor_name` field valued "foo", then this prints:

```
env var foo
global var foo
```

If the HTTP POST content does not contain the JSON field `actor_name`, then this prints

```
env var null
```

...then asserts/aborts with a `No such property` error.

Jenkins jobs also have a "this project is parameterized" setting, which seems to introduce yet another way to inject variables into your Jenkinsfile. The following Jenkinsfile prints a populated, parameterized build variable, an unpopulated one, and an intentionally nonexistent variable:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {

    stage( "Set up" ) {
      steps {
        script {
          echo "1 [${env.populated_var}]"
          echo "2 [${env.unpopulated_var}]"
          echo "3 [${env.dontexist}]"
          echo "4 [${params.populated_var}]"
          echo "5 [${params.unpopulated_var}]"
          echo "6 [${params.dontexist}]"
          echo "7 [${populated_var}]"
          echo "8 [${unpopulated_var}]"
          echo "9 [${dontexist}]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result is:

```
1 [foo]
2 []
3 [null]
4 [foo]
5 []
6 [null]
7 [foo]
8 []
```

...then asserts/aborts with a `No such property` error.

The pattern I can ascertain is:

1. `env.`-scoped variables will be NULL if they come from unpopulated HTTP POST content.
2. `env.`-scoped variables will be empty strings if they come from unpopulated parameterized build variables.
3. `env.`-scoped variables will be NULL if are nonexistent among parameterized build variables.
4. Referencing global-scoped variables will assert if they come from unpopulated HTTP POST content.
5. Referencing global-scoped variables will be be empty strings if they come from unpopulated parameterized build variables.
6. `params.`-scoped variables will be NULL if they if are nonexistent among parameterized build variables.
7. `params.`-scoped variables will be empty strings if they come from unpopulated parameterized build variables.

I have a few questions about this - I believe they are reasonably related, so am including them in this one post:

1. **What is the underlying pattern/logic behind when a variable is NULL and when it is an empty string?**
2. **Why are variables available in different "scopes": `env.`, `params.`, and globally, and what is their relationship (why are they not always 1:1)?**
3. **Is there a way for unpopulated values in parameterized builds to be null-valued variables in the Jenkinsfile instead of empty strings?**

---

Context: in my first Jenkinsfile project, I made use of variables populated by HTTP POST content. Through this, I came to associate a value's absence with the corresponding `.env` variable's null-ness. Now, I'm working with variables coming from parameterized build values, and when a value is not populated, the corresponding `.env` variable isn't null -- it's an empty string. Therefore, I want to understand the pattern behind when and why these variables are null versus empty, so that I can write solid and simple code to handle absence/non-population of values from both HTTP POST content and parameterized build values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is a bit complicated.

For 1 and 2:

First of all pipeline, stage, steps... are groovy classes. Everything in there is defined as object/variable.

env is an object that holds pretty much everything,

params holds all parameter ;)

They are both a Map, if you access an empty value it's empty, if you access an non existing one it's null.

The globals are variables itself and if you try to access a non existing the compiler complains.

For 3:

You can define "default" parameter:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {

    stage( "Set up" ) {
      steps {
        script {
          params = setConfig(params);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

def merge(Map lhs, Map rhs) {
    return rhs.inject(lhs.clone()) { map, entry ->
        if (map[entry.key] instanceof Map && entry.value instanceof Map) {
            map[entry.key] = merge(map[entry.key], entry.value)
        } else {
            map[entry.key] = entry.value
        }
        return map
    }
}

def setConfig(givenConfig = [:]) {
  def defaultConfig = [
    "populated_var": "",
    "unpopulated_var": "",
    "dontexist": ""
  ];
 
  effectiveConfig = merge(defaultConfig, givenConfig);
   
  return effectiveConfig
}
```

Comment: Nice, comprehensive answer, thank you. Do you know why, though: if a variable is populated from HTTP POST content, but that variable is completely absent in the HTTP POST, then the corresponding `env.` variable is null **but** if that same variable is populated from a build parameter, and the build parameter is left empty, then the `env.` variable is an empty string? I'm trying to understand the reasoning behind why one "path" of "variable not populated" leads to a null variable, but another "path" leads to an empty variable.

Comment: I'm not sure. But this could have something to do with the GenericTrigger plugin. In both cases is it a design decision. The plugin and the parameters are (most probably) developed from different people and even it not, the decision was different in both cases. I think the parameters are initialized with "" and in the GenericTrigger plugin not.